# How To Deal With 'Cannot Find Getter For Field' Errors?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I just pulled my previously android projects but now both giving this cannot find getter for field error.

Such as InstagramSharing.kt

```
@Entity
data class InstagramSharing(
    @PrimaryKey var instagramSharingId: String,
    ...
)
```

And when build(InstagramSharing.java)

```
@androidx.room.Entity()
@kotlin.Metadata(...)
public final class InstagramSharing {
    @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
    @androidx.room.PrimaryKey()
    private java.lang.String instagramSharingId;

    @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
    public final java.lang.String getInstagramSharingId() {
        return null;
    }

    public final void setInstagramSharingId(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
    java.lang.String p0) {
    }
}
```

But interestingly outputs 
`error: Cannot find getter for field. private java.lang.String instagramSharingId;`

Is there anyway to overcome this weirdo problem?

---

EDIT

After deeply analyzing, appeared that I-i characters causing this error. E.g in below model, while `progress` and `selected` fields not causing errors, `instagramItemId`, `instagramSharingId` fields caused.

```
@Entity
data class InstagramItemProgress(
    @PrimaryKey
    var instagramItemId: String,
    var instagramSharingId: String,
    var progress: String,
    var selected: Boolean
)
```

`error: Cannot find getter for field. private java.lang.String instagramItemId;`

`error: Cannot find getter for field. private java.lang.String instagramSharingId;`

Comment: Which version of Room are you using?

Comment: It was `2.1.0-alpha07` when pull the project then changed to latest `2.2.0-alpha01`, but same weirdness

Comment: Try using `val` instead of `var`.

Comment: @BirjuVachhani didn't solved unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My machine language was Turkish. I can't believe this, but changing the language to English solved the problem.

Note: I never want to misguide ones having same problem. In my case that's OK